# 「有効期限内にセッションに再アクセスがあった場合は、期間は延長される」のセッションとは？

Tags: php

**セッションの有効期限が延長される要件について調べているのですが、**
**[このページ](http://thk.kanzae.net/net/itc/t4082/)に記載されている「セッション」とは具体的に何を指すのでしょうか？**

> 有効期限内にセッションに再アクセスがあった場合は、期間は延長される

---

・セッションファイルの意味だとしたら、$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']は関係ないでしょうか？
・例えば下記の場合、session_start()を実行していないと思うのですが、$_SESSION変数セットを確認しただけで、セッションに再アクセスがあったことになるのでしょうか？
・あるいは、$_SESSION変数へ対して、値をセットゲットしたら、セッションへアクセスしたことになるのでしょうか？
・そもそも$_SESSION変数へアクセスすることは、セッションファイルへアクセスすることと、＝でしょうか？

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
  session_start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[この記事](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/7852213f478e8c5a2802#%E6%9C%89%E5%8A%B9%E6%9C%9F%E9%99%90%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE)にわかりやすく纏められていますが、

- セッションの更新：セッションファイルの更新
- 有効期限の過ぎたセッションファイルにアクセスがあった場合，**有効期限が再度延長される**．つまり有効期限切れのセッションファイルはその時点で無意味なものになるのではなく，**単にいつ削除されても構わない状態になるということを意味する**．
- `session_start()`でセッションを使用したことになる。(延長もこれを基準)
- > 例えば下記の場合……

  => この場合 `session_start()` **する**のでアクセスがありますね。(`$_SESSION`は初期状態では未定義)

ちなみにCookieはデフォルトではブラウザを閉じるまで、あるいは以下のように明示的に指定した場合は最初のアクセスからその時間まで(自動更新は工夫が必要)です。
くわしくはリンク先記事を読んで下さい。

```
// どのバージョンでも使える書き方
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

// PHP7.0以降で使える書き方
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7]);
```

---

(コメントの件について)
PHPのセッションはリクエスト毎に毎回呼び出さないと使用できません。例えば、次のコードを試してください。(var_dumpをブラウザで見やすくするために、あえてtext/plainにしています)

```
<?php

header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
ini_set( 'html_errors', 0 );

if ( empty( $_SESSION ) ) {
    echo 'セッションは空です' . PHP_EOL;
//  var_dump($_SESSION); // Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
    echo 'セッションを開始します。' . PHP_EOL;
    session_start();
    var_dump( $_SESSION );
    echo '現在日時を代入します。' . PHP_EOL;
    $_SESSION['current_date'] = date( DATE_ISO8601 );
    var_dump( $_SESSION );
} else {
    echo 'セッションは存在します' . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump( $_SESSION );
}
```

何度もリロードしてみてください。
初期状態ではセッションは読み込まれないので、「セッションは存在します」に到達することはありません。

初回：

```
セッションは空です
セッションを開始します。
test.php:11:
array(0) {
}
現在日時を代入します。
test.php:14:
array(1) {
  'current_date' =>
  string(24) "2017-02-14T05:55:14+0900"
}
```

2回目:

```
セッションは空です
セッションを開始します。
test.php:11:
array(1) {
  'current_date' =>
  string(24) "2017-02-14T05:55:14+0900"
}
現在日時を代入します。
test.php:14:
array(1) {
  'current_date' =>
  string(24) "2017-02-14T05:56:02+0900"
}
```

Comment: 有効期限内のセッションに対して、延長は行われないということでしょうか？　例えば、ユーザがページへアクセスしてsession_start()。23分後にアクセスしてもセッションは延長されない？　25分後にアクセスしたら、$_SESSIONが空になっているので、再びsession_start()ということですか？　質問した時点で知りたかったことは、有効期限内のセッション(既にsession_start()している状態)に対して、どういうタイミングで延長するのか、ということなのですが…

Comment: session_start自体は毎回リクエスト毎に呼び出す必要がありますよ？（リクエスト時点では常に`$_SESSION`は空です）

Comment: session_srartしてる状態で、という発言からしてもセッションについて勘違いされているようです……毎回呼び出すので、毎回更新される。そう捉えてください。

Comment: 回答コードを実際に試してみて、ようやく意味がわかりました。私はこれまで、一旦sessio_start()したら、セッションが切れるまで$_SESSIONに変数が残っているものと思っていました。セッションが残っている状態でsessio_start()したらエラーになる(と思っていた)ので、isset($_SESSION)で条件分岐するものとばかり思っていたのですが…。session_startする前に、if(!isset($_SESSION)){ と条件分岐する書き方は以前のやり方でしょうか？　それとも元からそんな書き方はしない？？

Comment: なぜ`$_SESSION`の存在確認をするか、ですがセッションが既に開始している状態でsession_srartを呼び出すとエラーになります。試しにsession_srartを2行並べてみてください。質問に張られていたリンク先で説明されているのはそういうことです。

Comment: なるほど、ようやく理解できました。大変参考になりました